# Variable becomes undefined after unset in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with a variable `$array` but after I unset the array, its says undefine variable `$array`

Here is my code which all variables are correctly assigned

```
$key = array_search($var, $array);
if($key == true){
    unset($var, $array);
    $imp = implode(',', $array);
    $cnt = count($array);
    echo $imp.$cnt;
}
```

Please why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `unset($var, $array);` unsets both $var and $array.

Maybe you want `unset($array[$key]);`